# Non default form submit leads to strange data transfer between js and flask application

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, form-submit

I am pretty new to this topic, so I try my best to describe my problem. I have a flask application that I try to use to communicate with the js of my front end. Here is my python file:

```
# python file
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import geopandas as gpd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/map",methods=["GET","POST"])
def map():
    py_data = {"geo_file": "false"}
    if request.method == "POST":
            geo_file = gpd.read_file("./DEU_adm1.shp")
            py_data["geo_file"] = geo_file.to_json()
            return render_template("map.html",py_data=py_data)
    return render_template("map.html",py_data=py_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

The idea is that when I get a post request from the js file the python files sends a geojson which is loaded into my frontend in a leaflet map (I left out the data from the post request since it is not relevant for this problem). When I am using the default form submit everything works just fine. However, when using jquery to customize this post there is some problem. Normally, I would expect to get the default py_data (py_data = {"geo_file": "false"}) in js when I do not post a request and when I post a request the geojson is transferred with the py_data. With the customized post request (with the jquery which is in my js/html file) the py_data always stays at the 'default version' even when I make a post request. So, here is my js/html code:

```
# js/html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form_post_map").submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $.post("/map",{
                dataset: "test" // some random data for demonstration purpose
           })
        });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form method="post" action=" {{ url_for('map') }} " id="form_post_map">
             <select class="inputs" id="input1">
                  <option value="1">Dataset A</option>
                  <option value="2">Dataset B</option>
                  <option value="3">Dataset C</option>
              </select>
              <div style="text-align: center;">
                  <input type="submit" value="Apply" class="inputs" id="submit_btn">
              </div>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I only included the relevant parts of the script, so all the code for leaflet etc. is not included.

Comment: I've tested your code from my side. It works correctly. You can add `<div>{{ py_data }}</div>` just after the `<body>` tag for a testing. The value of `py_data` is updated when you click `Apply`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I found out that since the ajax post function is an asynchronous task it cannot render a HTML template which was I trying to achieve. I guess you haven't tried it with rendering a HTML template? When I would just return a json instead of rendering everything works fine. But thanks again for taking the time to comment.